# Upgraded to 7.31 but getting "no pending updates" message

Tags: 7, upgrading

After copying over the files for 7.31 (was 7.26), minus the /sites folder, and running update.php, the result is "no pending updates." I followed the instructions at https://www.drupal.org/node/1494290 properly - any thoughts about what to do next? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to '[your-website]/admin/reports/status' and if there you see that Drupal version is 7.31 (which you probably will see), if there is no some other errors and everything works fine on website you successfully did update.

It is not necessary to always have database update if you are updating some module or Drupal itself.

Comment: No, it says 7.26. I had already done the upgrade on a local version of the site on my machine, and update.php resulted in about a half dozen updates.

Comment: Are you sure that you put a new (from Drupal 7.31) 'modules' folder ('modules' folder in the root, not in the 'sites/all/')?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Everything except the /sites folder - even uploaded the /modules folder separately to be sure.

Comment: Search your core code base for files containing `7.26` and see if an info file got missed.